# how can I calculate this gradient of function?

Tags: vector-analysis

I have encountered the following formula in one part of my calculations
$$
\int_0^\infty \nabla f(r).\nabla f(r) \;d\mathbf r\tag{1}
$$
I have read in Wikipedia that gradient of a function in the spherical coordinates is calculated as follows
$$
\nabla f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\hat{\mathbf r}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\hat{\boldsymbol \phi} \tag{2}
$$
I don't understand the meaning of $\hat{\mathbf r}$ namely vector of $r$ for my function because I have a function which depends on $r$ only and doesn't has any angular part so $(2)$ is reduced to
$$
\nabla f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\hat{\mathbf r} \tag{3}
$$
but I don't know how should I write $\hat{\mathbf r}$ in my case? Can I simply set $\hat{\mathbf r}$ to $1$ and write
$$
\nabla f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \tag{4}
$$
??
And what does someone say about:
$$
\int_0^\infty \nabla f(r) \;d\mathbf r\tag{5}
$$
??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\hat{r}$ is a vector, while $1$ is a scalar, so you may not "set $\hat{r}$ to $1$". However, if $f$ is radial, then

$\nabla f(r)\cdot \nabla f(r)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\hat{r}\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\hat{r}=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)^2\,\hat{r}\cdot\hat{r}$

and now you can simplify $\hat{r}\cdot\hat{r}$ to $1$ since it is a unit vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you tell me the answer for my last question which I just added to the question?

Comment: $df/dr\cdot dr=df$, so I suppose the answer is simply $f(\infty)-f(0)$...?

Comment: Thanks, however I didn't get your mean completely!

Comment: Sorry... What didn't you get, exactly?

Comment: where did go $\hat{\mathbf r}$?

Comment: You are taking a dot product of two vectors here, which results in a scalar... The dot product of $\hat{r}$ with itself is just $1$. Multiplying the integrand by $1$ makes it look like it disappeared.